# Locking specific cells vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel file that is locked from editing, all columns except column D are locked. The columns are unlocked and locked whenever the macro has been used. Now I want to lock some specific cells in column D without locking the whole column.

The criteria is that if column A contains the word "orange" then the same row in column D should be locked. If not it will stay unlocked.

Is there a fast way of doing this?

Comment: What is your definition of fast?

Comment: The fastest way would likely be to see a relevant portion of your existing code and the attempt that you have made to do this yourself. Include any error messages that you have received noting the line they were generated on. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The two fastest methods are *For i = 1 To LastRow* loops and the *rng.Find* method.
As per usual: avoid the *Select* method which does nothing in our case but slow down the process significantly.
You may also want to use *Worksheet On Change* events extensively as redefining the whole sheet's properties takes much more time than redefining the most recently changed cells' associated ranges'.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should help

```
Sub lockIT()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim willLockCol As String
Dim searchSTR As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("WillLock")
willLockCol = "A" '<---- Which column you want to search cells to lock
searchSTR = "orange" '<---- Content to lock
lastRow = ws.Range(willLockCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Cells.Locked = False
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If ws.Range(willLockCol & i).Value = searchSTR Then
        ws.Range(willLockCol & i).Locked = True
    End If
Next
End Sub
```